# What are these corn looking buds on my palm?

Tags: palm

In Florida, palm in our front yard is sprouting something that looks like corn?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just the buds of flowers - when they open up, they're quite a large arrangement of small flowers, usually yellow, sometimes cream or more orange, and sometimes scented. Some info with an image here https://www.hunker.com/12170377/how-do-palm-trees-reproduce

Comment: In case you or someone else doesn't know, that palm is Phoenix roebelenii, or miniature date palm.